# Do I lose the perks from Officer Training School when I destroy it?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

When I have every upgrade from the Officer Training School, can I tear it down or do I need to keep it, in order to keep the Upgrades/Perks?

Comment: Have you tested to see if you get to keep 6-person squad?

Comment: No, can't test since I am on a classic ironman playthrough^^

Comment: I can test it when I get home from work but I suspect someone is going to beat me to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XCOM wikia says:
"Removing the facility will cause all officer upgrades to cease functioning. Do not remove. The upgrades are not lost and can be reactivated by rebuilding the facility."

Comment: I can confirm that, as I once made the mistake of destroying the Officer Training School after unlocking all its perks. I can't say if it's still valid in *Enemy within*, however.